# Save radio button status php

Tags: php

Form table is introduced inside an echo and, for the texts fields, I use value=" ' .$_POST['name'] to set default value if form was already sent at least one time. It works properly.
However, how could I save radio buttons status when form was already sent? Thanks.

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"> <input type="radio" name="ambiente" value="si" />
         Si
<input type="radio" name="ambiente" value="no" />
       No</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
<input type="radio" name="ambiente" value="si" <?php if ($_POST['ambiente'] == 'si') echo 'checked'; ?> /> Si
<input type="radio" name="ambiente" value="no" <?php if ($_POST['ambiente'] == 'no') echo 'checked'; ?> /> No
```

Comment: Make sure to also check if $_POST vars are set, otherwise when you turn error reporting on you will get lots of warnings saying about undefined variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $checked = NULL;
    if(isset($_POST['ambiente']) && $_POST['ambiente'] == 'no') {
        $checked = 'checked="checked"';
    }
?>
<input type="radio" name="ambiente" value="no" <?php echo $checked ?> />
```

Or this can be shown on one line:

```
<input type="radio" name="ambiente" value="no" <?php if (isset($_POST['ambiente']) && $_POST['ambiente'] == 'no') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
```